# Кто из писателей первым применил существительное «поцелуй»?

Tags: этимология

Согласно этимологическому словарю,  слово появилось не ранее середины  18 века.  Вообще говоря, целовать – это желать быть целым, здоровым и невредимым, к романтическим действиям  «целование» имеет только косвенное отношение.

Лобзать – тоже целовать, прикасаться губами (от лат. labium "губа" ).   «Лобзай меня: твои лобзанья Мне слаще мирра и вина» - писал  А.С. Пушкин в 1825 году. Так говорили в 18 веке и в первой половине  следующего века тоже, но потом  слово уступило место  «поцелую» сомнительного значения. Но почему, как  и когда это произошло?  И характеризует ли эта замена каким-то образом русскую ментальность?

Интересная информация на тему:

1. В английском языке поцелуй обозначается словом «kiss», что происходит от древнеанглийского слова «cyssan», технически описывающего сам процесс поцелуя. Никто не знает наверняка, откуда оно произошло, но многие предполагают, что его произношение было похоже на звук, раздающийся при поцелуе.
2. Римляне, к примеру, использовали несколько разных слов для обозначения поцелуев в зависимости от их типа. Поцелуй в руку или в щеку был известен как basium, легкое касание губ было известно под названием osculum, а страстный поцелуй обозначался как saviolum.
3. Первое упоминание о поцелуях, как о романтическом поведении, было найдено в стихах, написанных в Шумере – древнейшей цивилизации мира. Поцелуи также упоминаются в древнеегипетской поэзии и даже в библейской Книге Бытия, где Иаков поцеловал свою жену Рахиль.
4. Историки считают, что эпидемия поцелуев начала распространяться по миру во время походов Александра Великого, после того, как он вторгся в Индию, где поцелуи были обычным явлением и практиковались на протяжении многих веков. Оттуда Александр перенял обычай целоваться и распространил по Западу.

http://www.bugaga.ru/interesting/1146745516-top-10-lyubopytnyh-faktov-pro-pocelui.html

Comment: « целовать – это желать быть целым, здоровым и невредимым» — эта версия имеет какие-то доказательства?

Comment: Материал взят из историко-этимологического словаря Черных.: целый  (здоровый, невредимый) - целовать.

Comment: спасибо. Раньше встречал только вариант с происхождением от «чело». Сейчас попробовал поискать еще варианты, но утонул в потоке бреда лингвофриков. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Черных немного ошибся в том, что слово поцелуй впервые упомянуто Литхеном в его Лексиконе 1762 г.
Из Лексикона Сергея Волчкова (1755) :

> *Un baiser*... **Поцолуй**, целование в уста.
>   *Baiseur*... **Поцелуйщик**, кто охотно целуется.

В Нацкорпусе первый пример сабжа :

> С. А. Порошин. Семена Порошина записки, служащие к истории Его Императорского Высочества Благоверного Государя Цесаревича и Великого Князя Павла Петровича (1764-1765)  Как назад ехали, то она ехала в салазках перед Его Высочеством. Тут, оборачиваясь,  друг другу **поцелуи бросали.**

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, правда, разница в о времени  несущественная. Интересно, а есть какие-нибудь источники, позволяющие проследить частотность употребления слова конкретными писателями, например в 18 веке.  Кстати, Словарь языка Пушкина что из себя представляет, можно ли его где-нибудь читать онлайн?

Comment: Запрос в Словаре языка Пушкина :  1. ПОЦАЛУЙ (поцелуй)ПУШ ,16319
ПОЦАЛУЙ (поцелуй) (36). Она чувствовала холодный поцалуй немилого супруга Д 220.19. Милее, по следам Парни, Мне славить лирою небрежной И наготу в ночной тени, И поцелу'й любови нежной! РЛ IV 149. К черкешенке простер он руки, Воскресшим сердцем к ней летел, И долгий поцелу'й разлуки Союз любви запечатлел. КП II 267. Душа твоя жива для дружбы, для любви, Для поцелу'ев сладострастья; С2 143.10. http://www.slovari.ru/search.aspx?s=0&p=3068

Comment: Спасибо! Интересно,  почему сначала писалась гласная А.

Comment: Поцалуй, цаловать - московский говор. В других местах окали : цолуй, цоловать.

Comment: Проверку не делали: целовать - целый? Но потом всё-таки перешли на запись с гласной Е.

Comment: Исходя из ваших слов, напрашивается вывод:" поцелуй" к "целому" отношения не имеет... Или всё же имеет?